# Including .NetFramework in my Setup file

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible that I could include .NetFramework installation in my setup so when user runs setup, all dependencies including .net framework are installed with that setup?
Thanks
Furqan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a Setup project at least the .Net framework should be handled automatically.

Quote: *For Windows Installer deployment, bootstrapping of the .NET Framework is enabled by default.*

See this link for further details about that and how to add other prerequisites: [How to: Install Prerequisites in Windows Installer Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7eh4aaa5.aspx)